# Qt5 Force TabWidget to resize on window size change

Tags: qt, resize, qtabwidget

I'm new to Qt and am trying to create a GUI application that will force the QTabWidget to resize to the maximum available size when the window is resized. I've read a few pages and questions on here but can't seem to get it working. Screenshot provided.

Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Once a widget is assigned to the centralWidget, select the centralWidget and then click a layout in the bar at the top.